# How can I access cucumber methods within a class?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Inside my class object, I want to be able to embed information to my log.

```
Class MyClass
  ...
  def my_method
    ...
    embed('my_stuff','my_type')
  end
  ...
end
```

When I try to run my method from within my class, I get an `undefined method 'embed'` for the class.  What is the path for running the cucumber embed method that passes information to the formatters?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: @sawa what do you mean my code is invalid? it's a class file, with a method, that I want to call the cucumber embed method on.

Comment: Whenever somebody asks for something weird, I feel like they want something else and think the weird thing will solve the other thing. Ask for the other thing, not the weird thing.

Comment: @DaveMcNulla I honestly just want to use the cucumber embed method inside a class.  We have a custom cucumber formatter that I want to log data to from within a page object.

Comment: `embed` is defined in `Cucumber::RbSupport::RbWorld`, if that's what you mean...

Comment: @RubyRacer if you try to call embed in a page object class, it will not work.  If you add `include Cucumber::RbSupport::RbWorld` to the class then it finds the embed method, but when it tries to run it the underlying @__cucumber_instance variable is nil

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 yes, that explains how to do it within the context of `Cucumber World` but when your within a class, you no longer have access to the `Cucumber World` anymore.  Didn't help at all